# Perl: Pdflib display wrong order with hebrew

Tags: perl, hebrew, pdflib

I have a problem with `pdflib`, perl and hebrew language.

When I input `עסקים`, it display `םיקסע` in pdf (order reversed).

I use `pdflib_pl` 3.02.

Comment: Does it also reverse entire sentences?  For example does בֹּקֶר טוֹב become טוֹב בֹּקֶר?

Comment: בֹּקֶר טוֹב become **בֹוט רֶקֹּב** @Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix a Hebrew string with &LRO; LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE to override the default direction of Hebrew text (which is right-to-left [according to pdflib](http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/manuals/PDFlib-9.0.5-API-reference.pdf)).